# Template monster api, how to convert the extracted data into an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, api

When i hit the URL : http://www.templatemonster.com/webapi/template_sources.php?login={my_unique_login}&webapipassword={my_password}
. Then this data is extracted from the template monster database:

```
1287     .PSD
1288     .PSD
1289     .PSD
1334     .PSD
1335     .PSD
1336     .PSD
1338     .PSD
1340     .PSD
1343     .PSD
1346     .PSD
1347     .PSD
1348     .PSD
1349     .PSD
1350     .PSD.AI
1351     .PSD.CDR
```

I want to convert this data into an array, so that i can make use of the extracted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

```
<?php
$lines = file('http://www.templatemonster.com/webapi/template_sources.php?login=...&webapipassword=...');
```

Then your have your array.